# PowerPivot Bar is grayed out

Tags: powerpivot

I'm trying to begin learning to use adding measures in PowerPivot but the PowerPivot Ribbon is pretty much all grayed out. Can you tell what I did wrong? How do I get the rest of the selections on the ribbon to not be grayed out?

Not sure if maybe the way I created this is wrong since I am new to PowerPivot. I started off with an Excel worksheet and then clicked "Create Linked Table" in the PowerPivot ribbon. Which then opened up my data in a PowerPivot window. Then I clicked in Pivot table within PowerPivot which put a pivot table back in my original file.

Here's a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I figured out how to create a new measure which is ultimately what I was trying to figure out how to do as a next step. But it feels like I ought to be able to do this from the ribbon. I can't. To add a new measure I have right click on the table name in the PowerPivot Field List window. Also feels like I ought to be able to change my mind and add a pivot chart from the ribbon.  But again I can't. I have to go back to the linked PowerPivot data table. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to have resolved itself on its own when i closed the workbook and opened it the following day. Now I can use the ribbon as expected (i.e. add new measures, open powerpivot window,etc)

Answer (score 0):

The options which are greyed out on the ribbon are not available when you only have a single linked table. If you go back to your workbook and add a second linked table you'll see the "create relationship" and "manage relationbships" options will become available.

Comment: But what if I want to add calculated measures?