# PowerPivot option missing Excel 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, 64-bit

After Windows updates installed on a PC and a reboot, for some reason now the Excel 2010 PowerPivot option is missing from the tab up top.

I looked over these two articles but neither helped resolve. I have reinstalled the PowerPivot software for both 32 bit and 64 bit and rebooted but it's still an issue.

I looked over these two articles and neither seem to help any.

1. [Microsoft Powerpivot button not working](https://superuser.com/questions/858375/microsoft-powerpivot-button-not-working)
2. [PowerPivot Bar is grayed out](https://superuser.com/questions/690795/powerpivot-bar-is-grayed-out)

Tried installing both these and then reboot.

1. PowerPivot_for_Excel_amd64.msi
2. PowerPivot_for_Excel_x86.msi

This is on a Windows 7 64 bit machine by the way and everything seems fine with everything just like other PCs. Any ideas what else I may try to resolve?

Comment: Check to make sure it's not disabled. File > Options > Add-Ins

Comment: @MichaelFrank That was it exactly, please add as answer and I will accept.  Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure the Add-In hasn't been disabled.

Click on `File > Options > Add-Ins` and check the `Disabled Application Add-ins` section.

[image]

If it is disabled, you can re-enable it by clicking the dropdown by `Manage:` and clicking `Go`.

Select the add-in you want to enable and click `Enable`.